# How to find out the current cursor position on a page?

Tags: itext

I add a bunch of stuff to a page, such as `document.add(p);`, then I add a table that fills two columns using the documentation [here](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=91). In this process, I use:

```
column.setSimpleColumn(
   x[count][0], document.bottom(),
   x[count][1], document.top() - height - 10);
```

where height is set to 0. This places the table in a column that starts at the top of the document. Of course, what I'd like to do is to add the column directly below the last thing written to the document (e.g. `document.add(p);`). If I knew the height consumed thus far on the page, I could manually enter the correct `height` value and things work fine.

The problem is, what gets written in the document depends on a lot of conditions, so I'd like to simply execute a command to tell me how much height has been consumed thus far in the document (for the current page) so I can set `height` appropriately. Is there a way to do this in iText (so that I don't need to keep track of the heights of each individual element added to the page)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three ways to add content to a PDF:

**Using document.add();**

In this case, iText decides where the content is added, based on the page size and the margins you defined.

There is a very old method called `getVerticalPosition()` that takes a `boolean` as parameter. I'm not proud of that method as it is a *getter* method that not only will give you the Y position on the page after using a series of `document.add()` operations, it can also change the current Y position (and that is not what a *getter* method should do).

If you pass `false` as a parameter, it will give you the current Y, which could be the position of the baseline of the last `Chunk` you've added.

If you pass `true` as a parameter, the method will first add a newline and give you the position of the baseline of the "next" line of text you'll be adding.

**Using ColumnText**

ColumnText is an object to which you can add `Elements`. You can then define a column using absolute coordinates and invoke the `go()` method. The `go()` method will render the content and you can use the return value to see if the content fitted the rectangle. You can use the `getYLine()` method to find the Y coordinate of the last piece of content that was added.

**Using writeSelectedRows()**

This method will only work when you work with `PdfPTable` objects.
The `writeSelectedRows()` method can add a selection of rows and columns to a page starting at a specific `x` and `y` coordinate.
It returns a `float` value that gives you the Y-position of the bottom border of the final row that was added.
If you want to know how much space the table needs vertically before adding the table with `writeSelectedRows()`,
you need to calculate the height of the rows you want to add first.

Comment: Thanks @BrunoLowagie, this works great and answers the question. But, interestingly, if I add a second table (of two columns), below the first table (of two columns), it always places this second table at the top of the page (on top of the first table). I think that's because the first table is positioned absolutely (?), and thus there's no way to place subsequent items relatively. Are there any known ways to address this? For example, can I compute height of the first table somehow (the portion on the last page only)? Or other technique?

Comment: If you use `writeSelectedRows`, then the tables will be added on top of each other. If you use `document.add(table)` for both tables, they will follow each other. Note that you can calculate the height of a table if you set the total height. That's useful because once you start adding things at absolute positions, you have to keep doing so.

Comment: I was able to align the second table below the first by using a `column.getYLine()` to get the end of the first table and use it to set the placement of the second table.

Comment: I used `column.addElement(table);` to insert the first table. Not sure if that effects your recommendation in your comment above.

Comment: Using `getYLine()` is perfectly OK! There are 3 ways to add a table: `document.add(table);` lets iText decide; `table.writeSelectedRows(...);` allows you to render the table at absolute coordinates; `column.addElement(table)` allows you to fit the table inside a rectangle you define. My answer (about `getVerticalPosition()`) is only valid if you use `document.add()`. I'll update it to include something about `ColumnText`.

Comment: Thank you for the clear and detailed explanations, and for creating a wonderful product (iText)!

Comment: Turns out `column.getYLine()` returns the y-height of the last row in the table. If the table has multiple columns, it cannot be relied on to set the location of the subsequent table to be placed on the page. For example, image a table with 2 columns, and the first column goes to the end of the page and wraps around into the 2nd column, which only has 1 row. Using `getYLine()` here would place the next table below the 2nd column's first row rather than starting on the next page. What would I need to key off of to determine the subsequent table should be on the next page?