# Cut table per page in iText 7

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I'm migrating some iText 5 code into iText 7. The original code writes a table into several pages with a text before the table in each page. Something like this:

```
void generateTablePages(PdfWriter pdfWriter, Document document) {
    int docOffset = 0;
    do {
        addLeadInformation(...);
        docOffset = addDocListTable(pdfWriter, document, docOffset);
    } while (docOffset < numberOfDocs);
}

int addDocListTable(PdfWriter pdfWriter, Document document, int docOffset) {
    [... creates a table ...]
    float remainingVerticalSize = pdfWriter.getVerticalPosition(true) - document.bottomMargin();
    int docIdx;
    for (docIdx = docOffset; docIdx < bklgReceiptEntries.size(); ++docIdx) {
        float tableHeight = table.getTotalHeight();
        if (tableHeight > remainingVerticalSize) {
            table.deleteLastRow();
            break;
        }
    }   
    document.add(table);
    return docIdx;
}
```

The text before the table (addLeadInformation) is not a header, the document has already another header. My problem is how to find the equivalent to **pdfWriter.getVerticalPosition** and **document.bottomMargin** in iText 7.

The expected result is maybe better understood with an image. This would be a result of one table cut after the first page is completed and then finalized in the second page. Please notice that the "*Lead information*" in each page is not part of the header. The header is contained in all pages, the "*Lead information*" is only contained in the pages with table.
[image]

Comment: Hi, the code is very vague and cannot be used to understand what is really being done here. Can you at least show how the result should look like? Chances are what you are trying to achieve can be done simpler, at least in iText 7

Comment: @AlexeySubach you are completely right. It is not easy to understand. I added an screenshot to show what is expected. Maybe reworking the code from scratch would be easier than migrating it.

Comment: It seems that the question is answered in the post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51953723/how-to-get-vertical-cursor-position-when-writing-document-in-itext-7. Marking it duplicate

Comment: @ArpanKanthal you are right. Thanks for the hint!