# Retrieve the coordinates of a Paragraph in iText

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I'm trying to retrieve the x, y coordinates from a `Paragraph` created in iText. I followed the approved answer in [How to get vertical cursor position when writing document in iText 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51953723/how-to-get-vertical-cursor-position-when-writing-document-in-itext-7) but I'm not getting the expected result.

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter("output/ITextSandbox/Coordinates.pdf"));
pdfDoc.setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.LETTER); // 8.5 x 11
Document document = new Document(pdfDoc);

PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(StandardFonts.COURIER, PdfEncodings.UTF8);
document.setFont(font);
document.setFontSize(10);

Paragraph paragraph = null;

// Print 5 lines to ensure the y coord is sufficiently moved away from the top of the page.
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    paragraph = new Paragraph();
    paragraph.add(new Text("Line " + i));
    document.add(paragraph);
}

// Print a new paragraph from which to obtain the x, y coordinates.
paragraph = new Paragraph();
paragraph.add(new Text("Line 6"));
document.add(paragraph);

// Follow the steps from the approved answer in
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51953723/how-to-get-vertical-cursor-position-when-writing-document-in-itext-7
IRenderer renderer = paragraph.createRendererSubTree().setParent(document.getRenderer());
float width = document.getPageEffectiveArea(PageSize.LETTER).getWidth();
float height = document.getPageEffectiveArea(PageSize.LETTER).getHeight();
LayoutResult layoutResult = renderer.layout(new LayoutContext(new LayoutArea(1, new Rectangle(width, height))));
float y = layoutResult.getOccupiedArea().getBBox().getY();
float x = layoutResult.getOccupiedArea().getBBox().getX();

System.out.println("x = " + x + ", y = " + y); // y should be approximately 630, not 710.
```

With standard margins and 10 pt font, the coordinates for the 6th line should approximately be x = 0, y = 630. Instead, I get y = 710.

Answer (score 1):

The code sample in the question *simulates* rendering on a certain layout area. That approach works to determine the coordinates on the page ***if*** the exact same elements are simulated on the exact same layout area.

In the question, only the 6th paragraph is simulated, so the larger y coordinate (higher on the page) is expected. To get the correct y coordinate, the 5 preceding paragraphs would also have to be simulated.

Moreover, the layout area is not the same as page. This code does not take into account the page margins correctly:

```java
float width = document.getPageEffectiveArea(PageSize.LETTER).getWidth();
float height = document.getPageEffectiveArea(PageSize.LETTER).getHeight();
LayoutResult layoutResult =
    renderer.layout(new LayoutContext(new LayoutArea(1, new Rectangle(width, height))));
```

With the default page margins of `36`, the correct layout area would be:

```java
float width = document.getPageEffectiveArea(PageSize.LETTER).getWidth();
float height = document.getPageEffectiveArea(PageSize.LETTER).getHeight();
LayoutResult layoutResult =
    renderer.layout(new LayoutContext(new LayoutArea(1, new Rectangle(36, 36, width, height))));
```

A much easier way to get the current coordinates after rendering some elements is:

```java
/*...*/
paragraph = new Paragraph();
paragraph.add(new Text("Line 6"));
document.add(paragraph);

Rectangle remaining = document.getRenderer().getCurrentArea().getBBox();
float y = remaining.getTop();
System.out.println("y = " + y);
```

Result: `y = 631.6011`

To illustrate the remaining layout area, let's draw it on the page:

```java
PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.getPage(1));
canvas.setStrokeColor(ColorConstants.RED).rectangle(remaining).stroke();
```

[image: PDF1]

With some different page margins:

```java
document.setMargins(5, 25, 15, 5);
```

[image: PDF2]